# How to replace a character in a file in C

Tags: c

i'm trying to find the occurences of a particular character in a text file , then replace it with another one . I've tried something like this `

```
c=fgetc(f1);
while(c!=EOF)
{

    if(c=='s')
    {
        fprintf(f1,"c");
    }
    c=fgetc(f1);
}
```

Comment: It is necessary to back the position of the file.

Comment: No, you can't do that. Partial code posted, but at best you will overwrite the *next* character in the file, and then read the *following* one after that. The file pointer moves on after each access.

Comment: I'd copy the file to a temporary file, replacing the characters and then delete the original file and finally rename the temporary file to the original file.

Comment: that's a waste @MichaelWalz especially if it's a big file,  he can do what he wants, just needs to see the linked duplicate  question

Comment: @WeatherVane that's exactly what happened , i've lost a character .

Comment: Please see @BLUEPIXY